# Click and move items ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

here is my problem in the following code,
I have 3 block which contains a text "Yolo"

it is in the 1 block I look for when I click on "Move to the right" the text "Yolo" goes in the 2nd block and the same when I click again and goes in the 3rd block

Do you have an idea ,how to fix this?

```
import React from 'react';

import './index.css' export default class Demo extends React.Component {   

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);;    
    };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="HereIsForFlex">
        <button>Move to the Right</button>
        <div className="test">
          <p> yolo</p>
          <div className="fruitsArrows">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="test1">
        </div>
        <div className="test2">
        </div>
      </div>
      );  
     }; 
    }
```

Comment: You have no onClick handlers in your code, how is anything supposed to work?

Comment: I had posted class-based components solution to stay as close as possible to your existing codebase. You might want to check [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149688/11299053) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply store within component's local state the string you wish to move, the number of available *'slots'* and current position of the string.

Then, simply use `onClick` event handler to increase current position:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM

class Demo extends React.Component {
 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this)
    this.state = {currentPosition: 0, totalLength: 3, val: 'yolo'}
  }
  
  clickHandler(){ 
    this.setState({currentPosition: (this.state.currentPosition + 1)%this.state.totalLength})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler} >Move to the Right</button>
        {
          Array.from(
            {length: this.state.totalLength},
            (_,i) => (
              <div key={i} className="slot">
                <p>{i == this.state.currentPosition ? this.state.val : null}</p>
              </div>
            )
          )
        }
      </div>
  )}
}

render (<Demo />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.slot{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;margin-top:30px;margin-left:10px;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:grey;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Neff : *'...if i want change the value 'yolo' by result on my bdd'* didn't quite get the point, would you elaborate or give some example (including expected output)? If that requires more than quick tip to answer your question, you may post it separatly and drop me a link here in the comments - I would gladly look into that too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working sandbox with the thing I believe you want to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-water-xy0n8

Comment: Click handler in your example increases `block` beyond the number of available positions up to infinity, which doesn't seem to be proper behavior. Also, it doesn't make sense to assign `id` attributes that never get used. Another suggestion is that you could've used something, like `map()` to make your block sections more flexible and appear in more concise manner. You may check out [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149688/11299053) below for example.

Comment: Yo man, this is a quick example for someone who struggles with basics, I wanted to make it as straightforward as possible, ```id``` attributes are there for semantic reasons and using ```map``` would be confusing

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov  Hey bro , if i want change the value 'yolo' by result on my bdd do you have idea or copoment ?